# Change color of the button and i class on hover

Tags: css, favicon

I have a class containing span and i class favicon. On hover I want to change color of the button and icon at the same time. How can it be achieved?

here is an example of my code:

CSS

```
a.btn.btn-seeinfo:hover .fa-chevron-right{
    color: #597692;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="btn btn-seeinfo">
    <span>"See info"</span>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: [Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1581/)

Comment: @Vucko The chevron color changes but text doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.btn-seeinfo:hover {
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<a class="btn btn-seeinfo">
    <span>"See info"</span>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve this by target class_name
like this

```css
    .btn-seeinfo:hover,
    .btn-seeinfo:hover .fa-chevron-right {
        color: red;
        background-color: transparent;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <a class="btn btn-seeinfo">
        <span>"See info"</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </a>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```